# Spring boot validate form

Tags: java, spring, validation

I'm following [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-radiobutton-and-radiobuttons-example/) in order to validate my form, but since I'm using spring boot I wanted to avoid the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

So instead of inserting it in the project I wrote a bean in my @Configuration class, obtaining this message:

```
Field validator in my.package.controller.MyController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.validation.Validator' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'resourceServerProperties' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken'
```

I have tried both those beans:

```
    @Bean
public Validator validator() {      
    return new org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}    

@Bean
public javax.validation.Validator localValidatorFactoryBean() {
   return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

with the same result.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remove those beans. You are stating you are using Spring Boot which already configures that bean. You don't need to inject anything you only need `@Valid` on the method argument you want to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify the OrderValidator as a `@Component` which implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator`, so the Validator implementation can be found and injected.